# Excel VBA code that copies data from one sheet into another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- Take a record of the busiest hour of each day, (i.e highest number of customers) and record its details (number of customers, amount spent, average time spent) into the second spreadsheet.
- On the second spreadsheet, a new column will be added everytime. It will have records of only the busiest hour of each day.

  ```
  Sub DailySales()
      Dim dailySht As Worksheet 'worksheet storing latest store activity
      Dim recordSht As Worksheet 'worksheet to store the highest period of each Day
      Dim lColDaily As Integer ' Last column of data in the store activity sheet
      Dim lCol As Integer ' Last column of data in the record sheet
      Dim maxCustomerRng As Range ' Cell containing the highest number of customers
      Dim maxCustomerCnt As Long ' value of highest customer count

      Set dailySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Supermarket Data")

      Set recordSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Record Data")
      With recordSht
          lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
      End With
      With dailySht
          lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
          maxCustomerCnt = Application.Max(.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, lColDaily)))
          Set maxCustomerRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)
          If Not maxCustomerRng Is Nothing Then
              maxCustomerRng.EntireColumn.Copy recordSht.Cells(1, lCol + 1)
          End If
      End With

      Set maxCustomerRng = Nothing
      Set dailySht = Nothing
      Set recordSht = Nothing
  End Sub
  ```

I get a "run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet failed" on the following line everytime I run the code (it is attached to a button on the second worksheet).

```
maxCustomerCnt = Application.Max(.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, lColDaily)))
```

This is the table:

```
Customer data   7:00:00 AM  7:30:00 AM  8:00:00 AM  8:30:00 AM  9:00:00 AM  
Number of customers 33         37         110          250        84
Amount spent        65         50          70           85        60
Average time spent  12         10           8           17        10
```

Can someone please help me figure out whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, lColDaily))
```

try

```
.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lColDaily))
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks. Is there a way to prevent data duplication? I.e. not record more than one data for a single day?

Comment: @aab - That's completely different question all together. I suggest you to kindly close the question by accepting answer that helped you and then ask a new question. New question will also attract more people rather than just two of us here.

Comment: @aab - Kindly mention the link of your new question here so that I can have a look too.

Comment: here's a link to my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45840040/prevent-data-duplication-in-excel-vba-code-that-copies-data-from-one-sheet-into?noredirect=1#comment78637880_45840040

Answer (score 1):

Mrigs comment is right, use `.Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(2, lColDaily))`

Just as explanation (as the error is so common): `cells` (without leading dot) refers to the active sheet. `.cells` (with dot) in your case refers to the sheet of the `with`-statement, you could write `dailySht.cells` instead.

So in your statement, you ask for a Range of the worksheet `dailySht` that is defined by cells from the active sheet (which is very likely a different sheet), which is not possible and raises the error you see.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the explanation.